# How to sort results by post_date DESC when using Algolia with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I'm using [www.algolia.com](http://www.algolia.com) as the provider to power the search engine for my client's Wordpress site.

It works great, but I can't figure out how to sort the search results by `post_date DESC`.

[I've created a "replica" table](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/ranking/how-to-sort-the-results-with-a-specific-attribute/) and added a `SORT-BY post_date DESC` as a "sort-by attribute" to the "Ranking Formula" using their admin console, but the dates are still out-of-order.

For example, the results will display *mostly* in order, but then there are anomalies:

- May 10, 2018
- May 09, 2018
- May 03, 2018
- March 28, 2018
- May 01, 2018

Anyone have any experience solving this problem with Algolia?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

By default the engine doesn’t interpret strings following the ISO date format. To enable filtering by date, you must convert your dates into numeric values (generally a UNIX timestamp).

```
{
  "objectID": "myID1",
  "date": 1362873600 // UNIX timestamp as an integer
}
```

For more info please refer: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/?language=php#filter-by-date

Hope this works for you.